# Why is ffmpeg so slow to create a video compared to CapCut, for example?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I'm just starting to use ffmpeg to create some videos that consist of: 1 mp4 file, then it overlays a png and adds the audio from a wav file. Nothing complex.

Using ffmpeg for a 2min30s video it took close to 10min to create.

I then opened the CapCut app and with the exact same files, **not even 1min.**
Opening the final videos side by side, there's no difference at all in quality.

Why is ffmpeg 10x slower than CapCut? Maybe other apps perform fast as well, but I just used CapCut as a test. Is there a way to make ffmpeg faster while keeping the quality, just like CapCut?

The only thing right now that seems to be more valuable for me when it comes to ffmpeg is that I can use a single script and create multiple videos while I'm doing other things, which CapCut can't, because it doesn't have a Queue, so I have to be there waiting for it to finish 1 video so I can export another one. Other than that, I don't see many advantages, at least for this particular scenario, of course.

Any tips?

Comment: It's very possible it's about hardware encoding and using the GPU. Those are configurable in ffmpeg but by default it might not be fully utilizing all possible resources.

Comment: Thank you @YisroelTech. I found this article https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-use-gpu-acceleration-for-video-processing-with-ffmpeg but when I use Terminal to check the compatibility I don't see the `cuvid ` or `vaapi ` this person mentions. All I see is "Hardware acceleration methods: videotoolbox". Does it mean I won't be able to make any changes to the processing speed?

Comment: I just found this (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro#VideoToolbox), but as a newbie when it comes to ffmpeg I don't know if this has anything to do with what you mentioned and if I can use this to increase processing speed?

Comment: At least try adding ` -hwaccel videotoolbox`

Comment: @YisroelTech thank you again. Your suggestion didn't work, but after a few more tests and looking at the second link I shared, I used this `-c:v h264_videotoolbox -b:v 6000K` instead of this `-c:v libx264` and now the conversion is FLYING! A 2 minute video converts in only **45 seconds**. Using the second option, on those same 45 seconds it only converts 16 seconds. What a difference! I truly appreciate your time and help on this! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few more tests, I used this `-c:v h264_videotoolbox -b:v 6000K` instead of this `-c:v libx264` and now the conversion is FLYING!

Using `-c:v h264_videotoolbox -b:v 6000K`, a 2 minute video converts in only 45 seconds.
Using `-c:v libx264`, on those same 45 seconds it only converts 16 seconds.